# Rails layout overruled by <section> html tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created my Rails 4 application layout based on a wrapbootstrap theme.
The main layout is placed at /app/assets/views/layouts/application.html.erb

As part of the implementation, I want to use some of the theme's features and add a  tag as part of one of the views.

Once I'm adding any kind of  tag into the *.html.erb view file, 
the whole outer layout seems to get rendered only after the  tag gets rendered.

I can't figure out why is that happening and how to fix this.

thanks!

p.s
I'm using ruby 2.0, tried on both Win and linux platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem wasn't in the HTML tag.

What I've done is to eliminate HTML comments from the partials code and everything worked like a charm.